# How to join two Kafka streams, each having multiple paritions?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two `Kafka` streams, `request` and `event` each partitioned on a common field requestId (last two digits). I want to join both the streams and write to `HDFS` or Local `filesystem`? How to write an efficient `consumer` which considers only the relevant `partitions` while joining the two `streams`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use *Kafka's Streams API*, Apache Kafka's stream processing library, instead of a hand written consumer. To write the data to HDFS you should use Kafka Connect.

For doing the join, look at this question: [How to manage Kafka KStream to Kstream windowed join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707854/how-to-manage-kafka-stream-to-stream-join-window/41708328#41708328)

Also check out Confluent's documentation about [Kafka Streams](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html) and [Kafka Connect](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) to get started. If you have further question, please start a follow up question (after reading the manual :))

Comment: Thanks. Looks exactly the kind of thing I need!

Comment: @matthias-j-sax I read the manual and both these libraries are compatible only with Confluent's version (Thanks to rationalSring for pointing it out). Are there any downsides to using the confluent's version?

Comment: That's not true. Confluent, just repackages Apache Kafka, and it's 100% compatible with ASF version. Only the HDFS connector is not part of Apache Kafka, but you can download it from confluent.io/product/connectors and use with ASF version, too. As Confluent offers Confluent Open Source -- and the code is 100% compatible with ASF Kafka -- there are no disadvantages using Confluent's offer -- only advantages as you get a larger software stack.

Comment: That sounds great! Thanks for all the help

Comment: Just to clarify. *Disclaimer: I am an employee at Confluent.*

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax any suggestions when topics can not be co-partitioned, thanks!

Comment: To co-partition topics, both must have the same number of partitions. If that's the case, you just use the same key for both topics to co-partition them. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka streams with Kafka Connect (for HDFS) is a straightforward solution. However, it must be pointed out that the HDFS connector for Kafka Connect is only available with the Confluent's version of Kafka. The Apache Kafka Connect only comes with a file writer and not HDFS writer.

Comment: How about using Flume to write to HDFS from Kafka?

Comment: That is no completely correct: Even if you use vanilla Apache Kafka, you can just download Confluent's HDFS connector https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/ and use it. Furthermore, there is no "Confluent Version of Kafka" -- it's just repackage but 100% compatible with Apache Kafka (it might contain additional bug fixed -- but this happens rarely).

Comment: @Rubbal, I have not used flume for that specific purpose.

Comment: @Rubbal will not be able to write to HDFS with Apache Kafka Connect. That is all I wanted to point out. But thanks for clarifying that confluent is 100% compatible with Apache Kafka. And since confluent has open sourced the code, it should be straightforward I guess. My team is also currently evaluating whether to go with ASF Kafka or Confluent.